# Is there a transformation from $n-$sphere to a $(n+1)-$cube?

Tags: differential-geometry, euclidean-geometry, transformation, spheres

Does there exist a smooth transformation (probably isometry) from $n-$sphere $\Bbb S^n$ to a  $(n+1)-$cube (with rounded corners)? Note that $2$-cube is a  square on $\Bbb R^2$ and $3$-cube is a usual cube (not filled) on $\Bbb R^3$ and so on.

Comment: What precisely do you mean by "rounded corners"?

Comment: No. For this would violate the rank theorem.

Comment: for smoothness of cube

Comment: @Vim, what is your means? the n-sphere and n+1 cube has same dimension.

Comment: @C.F.G $n$-sphere is a $n$-dim manifold whose ambience is the $(n+1)$-dim Euclidean space. By the rank theorem I meant the manifold rank theorem, not the classic rank theorem for Euclidean spaces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $X$ denote the $n$-dimensional cube, embedded in $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$ such that the origin is in the interior of the cube. The map $$\varphi:X\to S^n,\quad x\mapsto\frac{x}{\|x\|}$$ is a diffeomorphism. There is no isometry, as the cube and the sphere don't have the same curvature.

Comment: Thanks. What does this map? I think this map projects cube points in direction of sphere rays on sphere? am I right? Can be construct a map that be a variation of cube to sphere?

Comment: OP asked "from $n$-sphere to $(n+1)$-cube", not the other way around.